# Can I access to resources from different locale android?

Tags: android, locale

I have two locale in my application. Can I access to resources, for example string array from different locale without to change current locale ?
I mean with coding I don't like to change it in Settings.

Answer (score 36):

The better solution would be (if you're on API 17):

```
@NonNull
protected String getEnglishString() {
    Configuration configuration = getEnglishConfiguration();

    return getContext().createConfigurationContext(configuration).getResources().getString(message);
}

@NonNull
private Configuration getEnglishConfiguration() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(getContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
    configuration.setLocale(new Locale("en"));
    return configuration;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Wish I could back-port this and save myself the effort of messing with the `AssetManager`

Comment: Thanks! This is also the solution recommended by Google: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67672

Comment: Thank you Eugen.. This answer should be marked as correct one.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the code that work for me if cMK is String array from current locale and cEN is string array from diffrent locale

```
 cMK = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cities);

         Configuration confTmp =new Configuration( getResources().getConfiguration());

         confTmp.locale = new Locale("en");

         DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

         getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

         Resources resources = new Resources(getAssets(), metrics, confTmp);

         /* get localized string */
         cENG = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cities);
```

The current locale isn't changed and that was the point.

Comment: did you mean: "cENG = resources.getStringArray(R.array.cities);" ?

Comment: It changes locale for context (for your activity for example)

Comment: Constructor of Resources changes the locale of your app, so be careful restoring the original resource.

Comment: See the comments under the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244889/load-language-specific-string-from-resource on how to fix this

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You have to create a new `Resources` object specifying the intending `Configuration`.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#Resources%28android.content.res.AssetManager,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics,%20android.content.res.Configuration%29

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7 (so not android) Locale can be set differently for format resources and different for display:

```
Locale.setDefault(DISPLAY, Locale.PL);
Locale.setDefault(FORMAT, Locale.US);
```

Similar thread: [Changing Locale within the app itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/changing-locale-within-the-app-itself/14601938#14601938) .