# Android: programmatically get res drawable- name

Tags: android, resources, drawable

Is there a way to programmatically determine which drawable-dpi directory is used by a device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off of [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)

I wrote this to display the name of the drawable directory used by the current device:

```
private String getDisplayDirectory() {
    String prefix = "drawable";
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    if (metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW)
        return prefix+"-ldpi";
    if (metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM)
        return prefix+"-mdpi";
    if (metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV)
        return prefix+"-tv";
    if (metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH)
        return prefix+"-hdpi";
    if (metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH)
        return prefix+"-xhdpi";
    if (metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH)
        return prefix+"-xxhdpi";
    if (metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH)
        return prefix+"-xxxhdpi";
    return prefix;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a [`Resources`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#Resources%28android.content.res.AssetManager,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics,%20android.content.res.Configuration%29) object as shown in [this question about localization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10879185/2636001), using an modified [`DisplayMetrics`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) object.

---

Reading your question again, if you only wish to get the type of the screen, and not the Ressources itself, you can fill your `DisplayMetrics` object using `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);` as shown in the linked example, then evaluate the `density` instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) to determine that.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
switch (metrics.densityDpi) {
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH: {
       // Do your stuff if density is high
       break;
   }
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM: {
       // Do your stuff if density is medium
       break;
   }
   ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use the following to obtain the metrics:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```