# Compare strings in different languages

Tags: android, string

I am trying to create multilangualge app and faced with a problem! I have a string in `values\strings.xml` translated in German language `values-de\strings.xml`. I am trying to compare user input with those strings. If my input is in English and device's language is also English, everything works fine, but if I switch device's language to German and input a string in English, `contains()` and `equals()` methods will return `false`. Is there a way to compare strings in different languages? Thanks in advance! Also, sorry for my English!

```
 if (mystring.contains(context.getResources().getString(R.string.testString))) {
        check = true;
    }


 if (mystring.equals(context.getResources().getString(R.string.testString))) {
        check = true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code part where you use contains() and equals()?

Comment: yes before comparing you can convert the text in either of the one language..

Comment: But how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android when you call getResources() it will always get the resources of the default locale, to get one from other locales you must specify explicitly which locale you want to use, and you can find how to do it here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33629163/6171845

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot!!