# Specify locale in string resource identifier

Tags: android, android-resources, android-location

Is it possible to reference a string resource by locale, in XML?

For example, what if I want to read the French version of a string resource *no matter what locale I'm currently in*. This can be done in Java but can it be done in XML?

In other words, is there anything like this? `@string-fr/my_string`

Comment: did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6380008/1891118  ??

Comment: Yes I did. I'm looking for an XML-only solution.