# Can I set the string resource to a different language programatically?

Tags: android, string

I have a arabic strings.xml file. I also have an English one.

In my settings activity, I want to be able to change the language used by the user. Like, is there  a method like `setStringResource(string.xml-ar)`?

Comment: Do you want to change the app language only? Because if you change the phone's language, system will automatically use the appropriate language strings for you application (if you have specified). Please be clear about what you exactly want.

Comment: @MangeshGhotage my app language only

Answer (score 0):

duplication of [Load language specific string from resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244889/load-language-specific-string-from-resource)
check this one out.

Of course you must use `Locale.AR` or something like that for Arabic resource file.

Answer (score 0):

> Keep your language specific xml strings in the necessary directories under resources
>
> And change the locale as required

```
String language = "en";
String country = "US";
Locale locale = new Locale(language , country);
```

Comment: Is that all I have to do? The it changes the app to use the arabic strings.xml?